# Can't execute yolo/darknet from php exec - predictions.png never appears?

Tags: php, nginx, darknet

YOLO: https://github.com/pjreddie/darknet

I'm trying to run this from within a php script, but predictions.png never appears.  I assume this is a general problem with my understanding of how `exec` works, rather than how YOLO works.

I've changed the permissions and users on all relevant folders and directories to nginx/777.  I know that's not ideal but it's a troubleshooting step!

**What happens when calling darknet from the terminal:**

Logging output appears on the screen, and at the end of the process a file called predictions.php should be created in the /darknet directory.  When running this from PHP in the browser I don't care about the logging output, I just want the png file to be created.

Works:

```
/darknet/darknet detect /darknet/cfg/yolo.cfg /darknet/yolo.weights /path/to/photo.jpg
```

Works:

```
sudo -u nginx php71 -r 'exec("/darknet/darknet detect /darknet/cfg/yolo.cfg /darknet/yolo.weights /path/to/photo.jpg");'
```

Works from commandline (`php71 myfile.php`), but not in the browser:

```
<?php
exec("/darknet/darknet detect /darknet/cfg/yolo.cfg /darknet/yolo.weights /path/to/photo.jpg");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *doesn't work* is not a problem statement. What do you expect from this line of code and how it is related to predictions.php in the title? Do you have any errors in the log?

Comment: Firstly, that was a typo, it should have been predictions.PNG, my bad.  I've added a bit more explanation to the question, thank you!

Comment: Clarified further.

Comment: Sorry, still not clear what you expect from `exec`. It returns last line of STDOUT.  Also try absolute path to photo.jpg

Comment: I do have absolute path, I just redacted it, my apologies.

Comment: And I get it that the directory was not created?

Comment: Edited further :)  What directory?

Comment: sorry, I mean the predictions.php file in the /darknet directory. Do I get it right it is created when you run it from cli, but not when you run it from phpfpm?

Comment: Correct, thank you!

Comment: Try `$out = null; exec("/darknet/darknet detect /darknet/cfg/yolo.cfg /darknet/yolo.weights /path/to/photo.jpg 2>&1”, $out); var_dump($out)` It will show all output from the app and may shed some light on the problem origin.

Comment: Perfect, thank you: `array(1) { [0]=> string(33) "Couldn't open file: cfg/coco.data" }`

So there's a path problem when running from within php-fpm

Comment: Can I tell exec to act in a certain directory?  E.g. adding a "cd /darknet" before running darknet?

Comment: Not the php-fpm per se, but the fact that it runs in different context. When you run the script from cli it is executed in context of current user. If your app relies on some environment variables, they should be set explicitly. Refer to the app docs.

Comment: Seems that's as simple as adding `/cd darknet; ` to the start of my exec command, perfect!  Thank you so much for your help.